# yii2 using nginx for rewrite url

Tags: php, nginx, yii2

i'm trying to use Nginx to rewrite the url to more user friendly. Removing index.php?r= is success, but the problem is, after i tried to visit other page, it says 404 Not Found. I already add in the `config/web`  the urlmanager for pretty url but its not working . Can someone help me with this?

i'll try to post the code .

this is the nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen       88;
        server_name  localhost;


        location / {
            root   html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$args;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ .php$ {
            include        fastcgi_params;
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi.conf;
        }
    }
```

and this is the url manager .

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            // Disable index.php
            'showScriptName' => false,
            // Disable r= routes
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],
```

I tried this at my localhost first .

Thank You.

Comment: I Think you have to give the root path as root `/var/www/html/yii-app/web;` instead of `html;`

Comment: @Selvakumar when i change the root html as you suggest from `html` to `/html/yii-app/web`, this is the error i get in error.log.. `2016/02/23 10:13:53 [error] 3116#1344: *2 "C:/html/MAPUser/web/MAPUser/web/index.php" is not found (3: The system cannot find the path specified)` i place my nginx in C:

Answer (score 1):

Nginx config for yii2 Basic:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /path/to/localhost/yii2basic/web;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

[My fastcgi code.](https://doktorproblem.pl/nginx-fastcgi-conf/) - normally is in nginx config folder.

Yii config file:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',
        '<controller:\w+/?>' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
```

],

Comment: What if we're using php-fpm? Do we still use the fastcgi.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
  listen 84 default_server;
  listen [::]:84 default_server;

  root /var/www/your_project_dir_name/html;

  # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  server_name your_domain_name.com www.your_domain_name.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
  #
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```